# 'update-grub' and GRUB customiser doesn't work because of error in line 245

Tags: 14.04, grub2

An error occurred  while using update-grub & grub customiser.

I removed GRUB2 using `sudo apt remove grub2` and reinstalled it with `sudo apt install grub2` but still the problem persists.

[image: screen shot]

This are the contents of `grub.cfg`:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos9'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_IN
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-45-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-45-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
}
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-165A8E285A8E0529' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  165A8E285A8E0529
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 165A8E285A8E0529
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/31_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/31_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/32_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/32_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/33_memtest86+_proxy ###
### END /etc/grub.d/33_memtest86+_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/34_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/34_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/44_linux_proxy ###
submenu "Advanced options for Ubuntu"{
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/44_linux_proxy ###
```

I have no problem with dual boot since I have options to boot both Ubuntu and Windows 8. The problem is that I cant change the list order in GRUB via GRUB customiser or use `update-grub` command due to syntax errors at line 245.

Contents of `grub.cfg.new`:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_IN
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-165A8E285A8E0529' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  165A8E285A8E0529
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 165A8E285A8E0529
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/31_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/31_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/32_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/32_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/33_memtest86+_proxy ###
### END /etc/grub.d/33_memtest86+_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/34_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/34_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/44_linux_proxy ###
submenu "Advanced options for Ubuntu"{
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-46-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-46-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-45-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-45-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
}
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7 --hint='hd0,msdos7'  cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=cda9fe55-f8d4-43cc-b08b-432b648370ac ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/44_linux_proxy ###
```

Comment: Did you change GRUB configuration at all?

Comment: i did not do any thing with GRUB configuration file @muru

Comment: i posted, screen shot.
grub.cfg 
grub.cfg.new     files

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: no it is not @DavidFoerster  .i updated the question please look at it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solved by using boot-repair.
Install boot-repair in Ubuntu & open it. Proceed as per instructions. Detailed instructions can be found here on  [Boot-Repair - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and use 2nd option.

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: i updated  the answer @DavidFoerster

Comment: So that's basically the same as the question, [I mentioned earlier](/questions/594924/syntax-error-at-line-245-update-grub-grub-customiser/606814?noredirect=1#comment849367_594924).